# ORA-04098: trigger 'SYSTEM.BI_BOOKS' is invalid and failed re-validation

Tags: oracle, triggers, oracle10g

I am New in oracle. I am trying to create a table in oracle 10g with auto incremented primary key feature. And I am doing this creating trigger. I have created 2 tables 1.SERVLET_JSP_REGISTRATION and 2.BOOKS.

**Sql for SERVLET_JSP_REGISTRATION**

```
    CREATE TABLE  "SERVLET_JSP_REGISTRATION" 
("FIRSTNAME" VARCHAR2(4000), 
"LASTNAME" VARCHAR2(4000), 
"EMAIL" VARCHAR2(4000), 
"PASSWORD" VARCHAR2(4000), 
"ADDRESS" VARCHAR2(4000), 
"CITY" NUMBER, 
"SKILLS" VARCHAR2(4000), 
"LOCATION" VARCHAR2(4000), 
"PHONE" VARCHAR2(4000), 
"MARITALSTATUS" NUMBER, 
"ID" NUMBER, 
 CONSTRAINT "MY_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID") ENABLE
)
 /
 CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER  "BI_SERVLET_JSP_REGISTRATION" before insert on SERVLET_JSP_REGISTRATION              
 for each row  
 begin   
 if :NEW.ID is null then 
 select SERVLET_JSP_REGISTRATION_SEQ.nextval into :NEW.ID from dual; 
 end if; 
 end;
 /
  ALTER TRIGGER  "BI_SERVLET_JSP_REGISTRATION" ENABLE
 /
```

**SQL for Books**

```
CREATE TABLE  "BOOKS" 
 (  "ID" NUMBER, 
"TITLE" VARCHAR2(4000), 
"AUTHOR" VARCHAR2(4000), 
"DESCRIPTION" VARCHAR2(4000), 
"PRICE" NUMBER, 
"PUBLISHED_ON" DATE, 
"STATUS" NUMBER, 
 CONSTRAINT "BOOKS_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID") ENABLE
)
/


CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER  "BI_BOOKS" before insert on BOOKS              
  for each row  
begin   
  if :NEW.ID is null then 
    select BOOK_SEQ.nextval into :NEW.ID from dual; 
  end if; 
end;
/
ALTER TRIGGER  "BI_BOOKS" ENABLE;
/
ALTER TRIGGER  "BI_BOOKS" ENABLE
/
```

But when I am trying to insert a row on both the tables,SERVLET_JSP_REGISTRATION is OK but in case of BOOKS, it's showing an error "**error ORA-04098: trigger 'SYSTEM.BI_BOOKS' is invalid and failed re-validation**"--- can you guys tell me where is the problem and how to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, when you created the trigger, and if you had an error, it should have said, "compiled with errors."  run "show errors" to see the errors, or use an IDE that compiles and shows the errors for you , such as Oracle SQL Developer (free)

Comment: You can also query the `user_errors` view. Have you created the sequence? Also it's a really bad idea to create objects in the built-in schemas. Create your own user/schema and do all your work under that account.

Comment: Unrelated but: do ***NOT*** create your own tables or objects as `SYS` or `SYSTEM`. Do not do that, never. Create a regular user to work with.